# Merge list of strings into list of tuple of those strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, merge, tuples

I need to do this:

```
mergers ["co","nt","ro","la"] ⇒ [("co","ntrola"),("cont","rola")("contro","la")]
mergers ["co","nt"] ⇒ [("co","nt")]
mergers ["co"] ⇒ []
```

But I don't know how. I recently started programming in Haskell and I'm stuck trying to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this, as a first solution:

```
a=["12","34","56", "78"]
g n x= (concat $ fst y, concat $ snd y) where y=splitAt n x
h a = [g i a|i<-[1..(length a)-1]]
```

Comment: How can I put it in a function or call it? It can't be with predetermined values

Comment: I don't got the question. `h` is the function you have to call.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

mergers :: [[a]] -> [([a], [a])]
mergers xs = init $ tail $ zip (map concat $ inits xs) (map concat $ tails xs)
```

`inits xs` returns all prefixes of `xs` (including `[]` and the original list), and `tails xs` returns all suffixes of `xs` (including `[]` and the original list). Since the original list and `[]` are included, we have to use `init` and `tail` afterwards.

Here are some intermediate results:

```
ghci> inits ["co","nt","ro","la"]
[[],["co"],["co","nt"],["co","nt","ro"],["co","nt","ro","la"]]

ghci> tails ["co","nt","ro","la"]
[["co","nt","ro","la"],["nt","ro","la"],["ro","la"],["la"],[]]

ghci> map concat $ inits ["co","nt","ro","la"]
["","co","cont","contro","controla"]

ghci> map concat $ tails ["co","nt","ro","la"]
["controla","ntrola","rola","la",""]

ghci> let xs = ["co","nt","ro","la"] in zip (map concat $ inits xs) (map concat $ tails xs)
[("","controla"),("co","ntrola"),("cont","rola"),("contro","la"),("controla","")]
```

The last line shows why `init . tail` after `zip` is necessary.